# vb.net continuous textbox value in print preview

Tags: vb.net

i know this is just a basic problem but i can't solve it, can anyone help here because when i print preview my textbox value it continue all the way outside of print preview [print preview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYsCz.png), i would like to ask for help a code that the textbox value will authomatically continue in next line

code:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

 e.Graphics.DrawString("ENDOSCOPIC DESCRIPTION: " + txt_ENDODESC.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 610))

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `DrawString`. There are numerous overloads and the various parameters include the ability to specify the bounds in which to draw and whether to wrap within those bounds. You should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation BEFORE posting a question here.

Comment: Note that you ought to have a shortcut to the .NET documentation in your browser but you can get there from the VS Help menu and a few clicks. VS also supports context-sensitive Help, as Windows apps have for decades, so you can click a type or member in the code window and then press F1 to go straight to the relevant documentation.